An informal approximation in wave equations
I am reading Tao's paper, where he uses an informal approximation for the propagator $$
\frac{\sin\left(t\sqrt{-\Delta}\right)}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}\ \mbox{in}\ \mathbb{R}^{1+d}\quad\mbox{where}\quad d\ \mbox{is an}\ odd\ number
$$

He approximates the propagator when the frequency of $f$ is concentrated around $N$, stating that it behaves like
$$
N^{\left(d - 3\right)/2}\, t^{\left(d - 1\right)/2}A_{t}
$$
where $A_t$ is the spherical averaging operator:
$$
A_{t}f\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{\omega_{d - 1}} \int_{S^{d - 1}}f\left(x + t\theta\right)
{\rm d}\theta
$$
with ${\rm d}\theta$ being the surface measure on the unit sphere, and $\omega_{d - 1}$ the surface area of that sphere.
He refers to Section $\bf 1.1$ of Sogge's Lectures on Nonlinear Wave Equations for details, but upon reviewing that section, I found only the expression for the wave equation itself and not a clear explanation of how this
approximation is derived.
Could someone kindly explain how this approximation arises, or point me to the relevant details in Sogge's book or another reference that would clarify this ?.

Thank you very much in advance !.

I think I solve this question. From now on, I ignore any constant coefficient. If $f$ is of frequency $N$, informally, $|Df |\approx Nf$, and then
$$ \partial_t A_t f(x) =\int_{S^{d-1}} Df(x+t\theta)\cdot \theta d\theta \approx NA_t f(x) .$$
Let $k=\frac{d-3}{2}$,
$$ \frac{\sin t\sqrt{-\Delta}}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}f =(\frac{1}{t}\partial_t)^k(t^{2k+1}A_tf)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}t^{-k-i}\partial_t^{k-i}(t^{2k+1}A_tf).
$$
The leading term of $\partial_t^{k-i}(t^{2k+1}A_tf)$ is $t^{k+i+1}A_tf+t^{2k+1}\partial_t^{k-i}A_tf$ since interpolation.  Informal approximation shows that $\partial_t^{k-i}A_tf\approx N^{k-i}A_tf$. So, $\partial_t^{k-i}(t^{2k+1}A_tf)\approx t^{k+i+1}(1+tN)^{k-i}A_tf.$ Thus,
$$ \frac{\sin t\sqrt{-\Delta}}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}f \approx t(1+tN)^k A_t f.
$$
Since $tN \gg 1$ in Tao's paper, it means that $t(1+tN)^k A_t f \approx t^{k+1}N^k A_t f$.
